# How to add a docker volume mount to PyCharm on a Mac - missing "Docker container settings"

Tags: docker, pycharm

Using PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Professional Edition) on Mac we've set up a docker container and can run a Python script within that container successfully from PyCharm.

We want to add a volume mount to our Run Configuration.

On another ubuntu based computer, the PyCharm Run Configuration dialogue has a section titled "Docker container settings:" where the volume mount is added. On a Mac we're setting up, this setting is not present. Two screenshots show the difference below.

*Screenshot on a Mac (missing "Docker container settings"):*

[image]

*Screenshot on an Ubuntu-Linux OS (includes "Docker container settings"):*

[image]

Can anyone see why the Mac is missing the "Docker container settings:" section in the Run Configurations dialogue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps PyCharm on the Mac is not connected to the Docker daemon.

According to the PyCharm documentation, to connect to the Docker daemon:

> 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker.
> 2. Click The Add button to add a Docker configuration and specify how to connect to the Docker daemon.
>
> The connection settings depend on your Docker version and operating system. For more information, see Docker connection settings.
>
> The Connection successful message should appear at the bottom of the dialog.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Open the Services tool window (View | Tool Windows | Services or Alt+8), select the configured Docker connection node Docker node and click The Connect button, or select Connect from the context menu.
>
> [image]
>
> To edit the Docker connection settings, select the Docker node and click The Edit Configuration button on the toolbar, or select Edit Configuration from the context menu.
>
> You can also click the Add Service menu and select Docker Connection to add a Docker connection directly from the Services tool window. If you have Docker contexts configured, you can select Docker Connections from Docker Contexts to add the corresponding connections.

Reference: [PyCharm Documentation - Docker](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker.html#connect_to_docker) ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230212060809/https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker.html))